# Undefined index: password in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I am following the documentation and successfully able to login and send reminder using Auth library. However, while submitting password reset request form, I got "Undefined index: password" error.

```
public function reset_request(){
        $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'));

        return Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password){
            $user->password = Hash::make($password);
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash', 'Reset Success');
        });
}
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

I used these.

```
$credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'password_confirmation' => Input::get('password_confirmation'), 'token' => Input::get('token'));
```

And it responded,
"reminders.reset" rather than any redirection or failure. When i checked the database it has reset the first row user's password. I don't know what happened in behind!!!

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code, you should fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you answered in your Update,

`Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password) { ... });`

expects the first parameter `$credentials` to be an array containing the **email**, the **new password**, **a confirmation of that new password**, and **the token for this password renewal** as it sits on the `passwords_reminder` table but in your initial example you had only provided the email. That's why it failed un responded with `Undefined index: password`. The `$credentials` array parameter that you passed did not have the `password` key set to the new password as the internal code of the `Password::reset` method expected.